# Disable imports in ES6 displaying as "import ..." in PhpStorm

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, ecmascript-6, phpstorm

I'm currently struggling to work out how to turn this off, its small I know. But it bugs the hell out of me that every file I open I have to click the plus :O

**What is in the ...**

```
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as auth from '../actions/auth';
import Shell from '../components/Shell';
```

**What it currently looks like**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Settings > Editor > General > Code Folding

Uncheck "JavaScript imports"

Comment: argh my f'in savour!!! I'd been looking (logically?) in Editor>code style. I see now that wasn't logical! thank you